# How to implement deleting multiple rows in a database at once via datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a c# application with a connected database. The data is stored in a datagridview. How do I implement the removal of several selected rows from the datagridview and, accordingly, from the database.

here's what I tried, but in this code the last selected line is deleted:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  String cell = dataGridviewl.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].value.ToString();
  FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand();
  foreach(DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    cmd = new FbCommand("delete from " + nameTable + " where id=" + cell, connection);
  }
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Update();
}
}
```

Comment: You can build query with "id IN (id1,... idN)"

Answer (score 0):

You have only one FbCommand instance executed - the last one, you should either

1. Add several FbCommand instances into collection and then execute all of them in cycle (also change cell variable every time) -

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    cell = item.Cells[0].value.ToString();
    cmd = new FbCommand("delete from " + nameTable + " where id=" + cell, connection);
    //add to collection
  }
//execute every FbCommand
```

2. Execute every FbCommand when you create it

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    cell = item.Cells[0].value.ToString();
    cmd = new FbCommand("delete from " + nameTable + " where id=" + cell, connection);
    //execute every FbCommand
  }
```

3. Build query with "id IN (id1,... idN)" and then create FbCommand outside your cycle, and execute it only once.

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    cell = item.Cells[0].value.ToString();
    //build query
  }
FbCommand cmd = new (query, connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```